# English expression for "Dans la continuité de" in french

Tags: american-english, french

I would like to know how to say this french sentence "Ce projet ce situe dans la continuité d'un travail réalisé auparavant" in english.

Is "This project follows on a work realized before" correct ?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about translating a French into English.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it is about translating some French into English. Or rather, french into english, which is even less acceptable here.

Comment: Where should it have been posted?

Comment: danimal: You could pass **un travail réalisé auparavant** into Google Translate, which returns the perfectly good English equivalent [**work done before**](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/un%20travail%20r%C3%A9alis%C3%A9%20auparavant)

Comment: sure, there is always google translate but 1) it certainly doesn't always work and 2) even if it does it only gives one possible translation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about "this project is a continuation of previous work"?

Comment: Seems to be fine